# Reciprocal of the sum of powers of $1/x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Incidentally, I found

$$\frac{1}{\sum_{n=1} \frac{1}{x^{n}}} = (x-1)$$

where $x\ge 2$.

Please direct me to how others have developed the relationship. My computer cannot compute more than X = 500,000 so I just infer that it is always true.

Comment: This is just a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). Sorry, Im so vague for a long explanation, but you can find a lot of information about it here and in the net.

Comment: How did you get that? I'm getting $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^{n}}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x}}-1=\frac{x}{x-1}-1=\frac{1}{x-1}$

Comment: It's not true.  If y>x then $1/y^n < 1/x^n $ so \sum 1/y^n < \sum 1/x^n$ but y-1 > x-1.  Not compatible.

Comment: $(x-1)\sum_{n=1}^m 1/x^n = \sum_{n=1} 1/x^{n-1} -\sum_{n=1}^m 1/x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} 1/x^n - \sum_{n=1}^m 1/x^n = 1 - 1/x^m $.  So SUMto_m = (1-1/x^m)/(x-1).  If |x|>1 then inf sum = limit SUMto_m = 1/(x-1).

Comment: (-1) because I found this question on the Reopen queue after a pointless edit.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true.  It is a geometric series and for $x \gt 1$ we have 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^{n}} = \frac1{x-1}$$  For $x$ large, the sum is clearly less than $1$, while your expression has the right side much larger than $1$

The question is changed, and is now equivalent to the above.  The informal way to see it is $$S=\frac 1x + \frac 1{x^2}+\frac 1{x^3}+\ldots\\
xS=1+\frac 1x + \frac 1{x^2}+\frac 1{x^3}+\ldots\\
xS-S=1\\S=\frac 1{x-1}$$
More formally, you need to develop the machinery of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).  The equation is correct for all real $x \gt 1$

Comment: Maybe it's too late at night for me, but if the relation in the OP holds, why am I getting $$\dfrac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x^{i}}} = (x-1)$$

$$1 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x^{i}} (x-1)$$

$$1 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x^{i-1}} - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x^{i}} $$

$$1 = (1 + \dfrac {1}{x} + \cdots + \dfrac {1}{x^{n-1}}) - (\dfrac {1}{x} + \cdots + \dfrac {1}{x^{n}})$$

$$1 = 1-\dfrac {1}{x^n}$$

Comment: @Ross Your first equality is true for the sum beginning at $\;n=0\;$, not at $\;n=1\;$ , and it is true then for general $\;|x|>1\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio: No, it is correct starting at $n=1$.  For $x=2$ it reads $1=\frac 12 + \frac 14 +\frac 18+\ldots$, which is correct.  An added $1$ on the right from the $n=0$ term would spoil it

Comment: @RossMillikan You are completely correct. I missed the fact that the quotient here is $\;\frac1x\;$ , not $\;x\;$ .

Comment: Oh I found the mistake after a good night's sleep, the series in your answer goes up to $\infty$, not $n$

Answer (score 0):

A series is defined as

$$\sum_{k=c}^{\infty}b_k=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=c}^{n}b_k$$

And we can define a partial geometric sum as

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n}ax^k=a\sum_{k=0}^n x^k$$

To see the relationship of your question we must notice that

$$S=xS+a-ax^{n+1}\to S-xS=a(1-x^{n+1})\to S=a\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

Then we have the relationship

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^n ax^k=a\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

Then the value of the series

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty ax^k=\lim_{n\to \infty} S=\lim_{n\to\infty}a\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}=\begin{cases}+\infty\cdot\text{sgn}(a) &,\text{when }x\ge 1\\\text{undefined}&,\text{when }x\le -1\\\frac{a}{1-x} &,\text{when }x\in(-1,1)\end{cases}$$

Then the geometric series only converges when $|x|<1$. And for your case notice that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty ax^k=-a+\sum_{k=0}^\infty ax^k$$